# ngx-datatable - Setting a table height

Tags: ngx-datatable

I have an ngx-datatable with server-side pagination.    Given a page size of say 100 rows, the table grows vertically to display all the rows.  However, I want to keep the table to a fixed height though, say with a viewport that shows 10 and a vertical scrollbar to scroll through the 100 in the current loaded page.  (not using server-scrolling (scrollbarV)) - local scroll of the loaded page.

Is there a way to do this?

I also noticed that server-scrolling appears to use 5 rows by default even if my page size is say 100.  Is that a setting somewhere?